# Using a Django custom model method property in order_by()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently learning Django and some of my models have custom methods to get values formatted in a specific way. Is it possible to use the value of one of these custom methods that I've defined as a property in a model with order_by()?

Here is an example that demonstrates how the property is implemented.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name='e-mail')

    def _get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    full_name = property(_get_full_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

With this model I can do:

```
>>> Author.objects.all()
[<Author: John Doh>, <Author: Jane Doh>, <Author: Andre Miller>]
>>> Author.objects.order_by('first_name')
[<Author: Andre Miller>, <Author: Jane Doh>, <Author: John Doh>]
```

But I cannot do:

```
>>> Author.objects.order_by('full_name')
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'full_name' into field. Choices are: book, email, first_name, id, last_name
```

What would be the correct way to use order_by on a custom property like this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No, you can't do that. `order_by` is applied at the database level, but the database can't know anything about your custom Python methods.

You can either use the separate fields to order:

```
Author.objects.order_by('first_name', 'last_name')
```

or do the ordering in Python:

```
sorted(Author.objects.all(), key=lambda a: a.full_name)
```

Comment: Maybe `F()` objects will work in this case. Haven't tested, but maybe ordering by `F('first_name')+' '+F('last_name')`?

Comment: To sort by _multiple_ custom fields with `sorted` you can use key=attrgetter as described at https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: For `sorted(CGHSSection.objects.all(), key=lambda a: a.modtitle)`, I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method'`

Comment: @JoelGMathew https://stackoverflow.com/a/51929973/4329778