# Is it possible to order_by with a callable?

Tags: django, aggregate, django-queryset

**DUPLICATE:** [Using a Django custom model method property in order_by()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981375/using-a-django-custom-model-method-property-in-orderby)

I have two models;  one that stores posts and another that stores votes made on those posts, related using a ForeignKey field.  Each vote is stored as a separate record since I need to track the user and datetime that the vote was cast.

I've created a helper function that tallys all the votes using the Django 1.1 aggregation Sum function.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...some fields...

    def tally(self):
        return self.vote_set.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum'] or 0

class Vote(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    ...some fields...
```

One query I need to make needs to do a one off `order_by` of the tally.  However:

```
Post.objects.all().order_by('tally')
```

yields the following template error:

> Caught an exception while rendering:
>   Cannot resolve keyword 'tally' into
>   field. Choices are: date_created,
>   description, id, is_active, name,
>   related, slug, user, vote

It there any way to get the `order_by()` function to take a callable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the Annotate method was the solution:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(vote_tally=Sum('vote__value')).order_by('-vote_tally')
```

Comment: btw, using `.all()` is redundant