# Order by method in model

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have 2 models `Car` and `Rating`. People rate cars (duhh). I have wrote a simple `get_average_score()` method which gets the average score of the `Car`, below are my models.

```
class Car(models.Model):
  def get_average_score(self):
    return self.rating_set.aggregate(Avg('score'))

class Rating(models.Model):
  car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
  score = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Basically what i want is "Top Cars", where I'm ordering `get_average_score()` desc.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you could do this using annotate e.g.

```
Car.objects.annotate(score=Avg('rating__score').order_by('-score')
```

Comment: That would be Avg, i thought you could render that method as a property, so i could do order_by('-get_average_score')

Comment: Yep sorry avg, as far as i thought you could not order by custom method.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but as you said you cannot order by custom methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981375/using-a-django-custom-model-method-property-in-order-by