# '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method' - Python, Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do Winerama Recommender [Tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/build-data-products-django-machine-learning-clustering-user-preferences-du107s5mk) . I met a error which I can't solve. When I try to go to the tab 'recommendation list' the browser returned the following error.

**Error**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/recommendation/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'reviews',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\Cd-12.50-20.08\env\my_app\winerama\reviews\views.py" in user_recommendation_list
  89.         reverse=True

Exception Type: TypeError at /recommendation/
Exception Value: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method'
```

I created everything according to the steps in the tutorial.

**File models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import numpy as np


class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = [list(map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all()))]
        return np.mean(all_ratings)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)

class Cluster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_members(self):
        return "\n".join([u.username for u in self.users.all()])
```

Next i added **admin.py** and create 3 klaster with users in '/admin'.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Wine, Review, Cluster

class ReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Review
    list_display = ('wine', 'rating', 'user_name', 'comment', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ['pub_date', 'user_name']
    search_fields = ['comment']


class ClusterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Cluster
    list_display = ['name', 'get_members']


admin.site.register(Wine)
admin.site.register(Review, ReviewAdmin)
admin.site.register(Cluster, ClusterAdmin)
```

**My file views.py**

```
@login_required
def user_recommendation_list(request):
    # get request user reviewed wines
    user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_name=request.user.username).prefetch_related('wine')
    user_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, user_reviews))

    # get request user cluster name (just the first one righ now)
    user_cluster_name = \
        User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).cluster_set.first().name

    # get usernames for other memebers of the cluster
    user_cluster_other_members = \
        Cluster.objects.get(name=user_cluster_name).users \
            .exclude(username=request.user.username).all()
    other_members_usernames = set(map(lambda x: x.username, user_cluster_other_members))

    # get reviews by those users, excluding wines reviewed by the request user
    other_users_reviews = \
        Review.objects.filter(user_name__in=other_members_usernames) \
            .exclude(wine__id__in=user_reviews_wine_ids)
    other_users_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, other_users_reviews))

    # then get a wine list including the previous IDs, order by rating
    wine_list = sorted(
        list(Wine.objects.filter(id__in=other_users_reviews_wine_ids)),
        key=lambda x: x.average_rating,
        reverse=True
    )

    return render(
        request,
        'reviews/user_recommendation_list.html',
        {'username': request.user.username, 'wine_list': wine_list}
    )
```

I will mark that when I try use simple version everything works fine.

```
@login_required
def user_recommendation_list(request):
    # get this user reviews
    user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_name=request.user.username).prefetch_related('wine')
    # from the reviews, get a set of wine IDs
    user_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, user_reviews))
    # then get a wine list excluding the previous IDs
    wine_list = Wine.objects.exclude(id__in=user_reviews_wine_ids)

    return render(
        request,
        'reviews/user_recommendation_list.html',
        {'username': request.user.username,'wine_list': wine_list}
    )
```

My error is at this [stage (2.5)](https://github.com/jadianes/winerama-recommender-tutorial/tree/stage-2.5) of the tutorial. Stage 2.4 works good. 
Everything indicates that something is wrong in views.py.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `average_rating` is a function *not* an attribute/property. Can you share the `Wine` model?

Comment: of course, I've added the whole models.py file above

Comment: That's a terrible tutorial; the author appears to have no idea how to do cross-model queries. There is no reason for all this repeated set/map/lambda stuff. For instance, the one in the "simple version" could be replaced by just `Wine.objects.exclude(review__user_name=request.user.username)`. But additionally the review should have a foreign key to User, rather than storing the user_name as a CharField. Really, you should find a better tutorial.

Comment: Also note that `User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` is just a waste of processor cycles and developer's brain time - `request.user` IS the very same object.

Comment: Plus, they shouldn't be calculating `average_rating` in Python, nor should they be sorting in Python based on that calculation. Both of those should be done in the database, using annotations and ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will have to do a better tutorial. Maybe you've heard about some good tutorial similar to this (it means, showing how machine learning works)?

I will also add some interesting links after searching the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`sorted()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.sorted) function accepts function `key` that returns value. Seems like x.average_rating is method, not the value. So you have 2 choices

- add () after x.average_rating
- convert x.average_rating to [property](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.property)

Comment: Or, maybe more elegantly, not use a lambda at all when you have a function already: `key=Wine.average_rating`

Comment: thank you very much, of course adding 'add () po x.average_rating' solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between a *method* and the value a method returns. Here in your `Wine` model, we see:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def average_rating(self):
        return self.review_set.aggregate(
            mean=Avg('rating')
        )['mean']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

(I rewrote it to make an efficienty query, instead of Python/Django/Numpy let do the work).

If you now have a `Wine` object named `some_wine`, then you do not get the average rating here with `some_wine.average_rating`, since this will return a method, but by *calling* the function, so `some_wine.average_rating()`.

There are some options here:

1. calling the function in the *lambda expression*:

   ```
   wine_list = sorted(
       list(Wine.objects.filter(id__in=other_users_reviews_wine_ids)),
       key=lambda x: x.average_rating(),
       reverse=True
   )
   ```
2. define the method as a property, in that case, you no longer *call* the function, it is the called behind the curtains, so:

   ```
   from django.db.models import Avg

   class Wine(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     @property
     def average_rating(self):
         return self.review_set.aggregate(
             mean=Avg('rating')
         )['mean']

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
   ```
3. use `Wine.average_rating` as key, since then it is a function that is *called* with instances:

   ```
   wine_list = sorted(
       list(Wine.objects.filter(id__in=other_users_reviews_wine_ids)),
       key=Wine.average_rating,
       reverse=True
   )
   ```
4. *order* the `Wine` objects already by the database, by using `.annotate(..)`:

   ```
   wine_list = Wine.objects.filter(
       id__in=other_users_reviews_wine_ids
   ).annotate(
       mean=Avg('rating')
   ).order_by('-rating')
   ```

The latest approach is probably the most efficient, since a database typically is optimized for such queries, furthermore this will get done by a *single* query.